# Is the question correct? Prove if $\frac{a}{b - c}+\frac{b}{c-a}+\frac{c}{a - b}=0$ then $\frac{a}{(b - c)^2}+\frac{b}{(c-a)^2}+\frac{c}{(a - b)^2}=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am reading a book containing some advanced problems in basic algebra, and I encountered this problem. I am not sure if it is correct:

Prove if $\frac{a}{b - c} + \frac{b}{c-a} + \frac{c}{a - b}=0$

then $\frac{a}{(b - c)^2} + \frac{b}{(c-a)^2} + \frac{c}{(a - b)^2}=0$

I wrote $\frac{a}{(b - c)}$ as $\frac{b}{a-c} + \frac{c}{b-a}$ and as a result

$\frac{a}{(b - c)^2} = \frac{1}{a}(\frac{b}{a-c} + \frac{c}{b-a})^2$

and then I tried to simplify $\frac{1}{a}(\frac{b}{a-c} + \frac{c}{b-a})^2 + \frac{b}{(c-a)^2} + \frac{c}{(a - b)^2}$ but this does not add up to zero.

I know the book has some typos, and I am wondering if this is a typo too.

If the question is correct please give your answer too.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hint: $\frac{a}{(b-c)^2}=\frac{b^2-c^2+ca-ab}{(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)}$.